# Re-factorize a program using single responsibility principle - SOLID- SRP

Tags: c#, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I am learning SOLID and I am trying to understand the Single Responsibility Principle.

The class WalkingData storages a "date" and a "walked distance". The class also read the stored data.

```
 public class WalkingData
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int WalkedDistance { get; set; }
        private string _filePath = @"c:\Data\Json.txt";

        //Read Data from Json File
        public List<WalkingData> GetAll()
        {
            //If file does not exist returns an empty list
            if (!File.Exists(_filePath)) return new List<WalkingData>();

            string jsonData;

            //Read the existing Json file
            using (StreamReader readtext = new StreamReader(_filePath))
            {
                jsonData = readtext.ReadToEnd();
            }

            //Deserialize the Json and returs a list of WalkingData
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WalkingData>>(jsonData);            
        }

        //save an instance of  WalkingData in Json file
        public void Save()
        {
            List<WalkingData> lstExistingWalkingData = new List<WalkingData>();

            //if existing data, load it into lstExistingWalkingData
            if (File.Exists(_filePath))
                lstExistingWalkingData = GetAll();

            //Add the current instace into lstExistingWalkingData
            lstExistingWalkingData.Add(this);

            //Serialize lstExistingWalkingData
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstExistingWalkingData);

            //Save the Json file
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(_filePath))
            {
                w.WriteLine(output);
            }
        }      
    }
```

After I applied the Single Responsabibly Principle  I have the new code that I would like to confirm if I applied the principle in a reasonable way:

```
//This class is located on a library called BOL and has a reference to DAL library
    public class WalkingData
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int WalkedDistance { get; set; }
    }

    //This class is located on a library called BOL and has a reference to DAL library
    public class WalkingDataManager
    {        
        WalkingDataRepository walkingDataRepository = new WalkingDataRepository();

        public List<WalkingData> GetAll()
        {
            return walkingDataRepository.GetAll();
        }

        public void Save(WalkingData walkingData)
        {
            walkingDataRepository.Save(walkingData);
        }
    }

    //this class is located in library Called DAL
    internal class WalkingDataRepository
    {
        private string _filePath = @"c:\Data\Json.txt";

        //Read Data from Json File
        internal List<WalkingData> GetAll()
        {
            //If file does not exist returns an empty list
            if (!File.Exists(_filePath)) return new List<WalkingData>();

            string jsonData;

            //Read the existing Json file
            using (StreamReader readtext = new StreamReader(_filePath))
            {
                jsonData = readtext.ReadToEnd();
            }

            //Deserialize the Json and returs a list of WalkingData
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WalkingData>>(jsonData);
        }

        //save an instance of  WalkingData in Json file
        internal void Save(WalkingData walkingData)
        {
            List<WalkingData> lstExistingWalkingData = new List<WalkingData>();

            //if existing data, load it into lstExistingWalkingData
            if (File.Exists(_filePath))
                lstExistingWalkingData = GetAll();

            //Add the current instace into lstExistingWalkingData
            lstExistingWalkingData.Add(walkingData);

            //Serialize lstExistingWalkingData
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstExistingWalkingData);

            //Save the Json file
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(_filePath))
            {
                w.WriteLine(output);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check the help page on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to see if such a question is suitable for asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and consider doing that.

Comment: Quick one don't use new keyword. Remember new is glue. Use DI to resolve your dependecies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You separated the responsibility of saving data (`WalkingDataRepository`) and also encapsulated it within `WalkingDataManager`. The refactoring work totally aligns with what SRP says. In short, the SRP is not just about breaking down the functionalities but also about encapsulating them! I also [wrote an article](https://medium.com/p/the-single-responsibility-principle-is-not-so-simple-524a83b2b710) about it.

What bothers me is the [anemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) `WalkingData` model. This is an anti-pattern. You should rather let `WalkingData` handle the responsibility of maintaining its own data rather than creating another class `WalkingDataManager` to do that job.